# MailMessage "losing" actual message when sending

Tags: c#, asp.net, mailmessage

I created custom email provider and need to read email messages to check for specific strings.

If they exists I stop the email from sending. This work to a certain extent.
My issue is that some email are sent empty (no content).

```
protected override void SendEmailAsyncInternal(string siteName, MailMessage message, SMTPServerInfo smtpServer, EmailToken emailToken)
{
    string contentAll = "";
    bool stopEmail = false;

    // read email content
    try
    {
        if (message.AlternateViews.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < message.AlternateViews.Count; i++)
            {
               var stream = message.AlternateViews[i].ContentStream;
               if (stream.CanRead)
                {
                    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, false, 99999, true))
                    {
                        contentAll += reader.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // log event
    }

    if (stopEmail)
    {
       // mark email as DENIED
    }

    base.SendEmailAsyncInternal(siteName, message, smtpServer, emailToken);
}
```

I know it has to do with reading the stream:

```
if (stream.CanRead)
{
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, false, 99999, true))
    {
        contentAll += reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

I have tried copying to temp stream but had the same issue:

```
 var stream = message.AlternateViews[i].ContentStream;
 //////
 //Temporary Stream
 MemoryStream tempStream = new MemoryStream();
 stream.CopyTo(tempStream);

 //
 if (tempStream.CanRead)
 {
     //  tempStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
     tempStream.Position = 0;
     using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(tempStream, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, false, 99999, true))
     {
         contentAll += reader.ReadToEnd();
     }
 }
```

Why is this one line of code stripping the content of the email that is sent?

```
contentAll += reader.ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: Probably because the stream (after being read) points to the end of the data and is therefore "empty".

Comment: So how can I move back to start?

Comment: Depends on the actual type of the Stream and how the data is represented. You could try `stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)` but if the stream is just a subpart of the entire message that could mess it up even more.

Comment: If the Stream is for example a MemoryStream it should be easy. Simply remember the `Position` of that, run `ToArray` or `CopyTo` and reset the position.

Comment: Thanks @ManfredRadlwimmer .  Adding stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)  did the job